# Why Doesn't Text Display On iPhone

Tags: html, iphone, ios, slider

On a slider I have on my site, for some reason iPhone users are reporting that the text in the main slider (royal slider) isn't displaying. I've tested it in multiple online simulators (but they've probably just been restricting the size, rather than using the iPhones rendering engine) and have yet to replicate the issue.

It works fine for me on Android devices, but can't figure out what would stop it from showing on an iPhone.

Any ideas why?
Here's the url [Issue is in the main slider in "Breaking" news section](http://www.agriland.ie)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the royalslider.css file is telling the `<a>` containing the text to hide in Safari (desktop and mobile) browsers. Check Safari on the desktop and you'll see the following CSS on line 29 of `royalslider.css`.

-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;

You'll probably want to override the value in your CSS file.

Here's some [info on `backface-visibility`](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/backface-visibility/)

Comment: Brilliant that worked a treat for me! Thanks a bunch, strange that it was set like that..